# Looking for: Easy header-design for (mathematical) work sheets in scrartcl-class

Tags: header-footer, templates

I am searching for a template, sample or some workaround to design math work sheets. I'm especially interested in designing the header of the sheets, which should include the faculty, department and prof. Furthermore lecture name, year and number of excercises; see this example: [image: Header example for math work sheets]

I would like to stick to my documentclass "scrartcl". I've seen some some other classes like https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathexam but feel more comfortable working with a documentclass I know (to prevent subsequent surprises/problems). Thanks

Comment: Package `scrlayer-scrpage` is the only package for header/footer customization with a KOMA-class. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package scrlayer-scrpage is the only package for header/footer customization with a KOMA-class.

[image: macKomaHeader]

```
\documentclass[headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead*{\begin{tabular}{l}
    Mathematics Tutorial\\
    Summer Term 2014\\
    \\
Some Name\\
Some Mail\end{tabular}
}
\chead*{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}
\ohead*{\begin{tabular}{r}MLU Halle\\Jur und WiWi-Fak\\BWL\\
    Some Prof\\ Some mathematician\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used this modification:

```
\documentclass[headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=0.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}      

\ihead{\begin{tabular}{l}
    Mathematics Tutorial\\
    Summer Term 2014\\
    \\
Some Name\\
Some Mail\end{tabular}
}
\chead{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}
\ohead{\begin{tabular}{r}MLU Halle\\Jur und WiWi-Fak\\BWL\\
    Some Prof\\ Some mathematician\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The "geometry"-package, because the header was much to far away from the top (in my opinion). And I still don't know why you placed stars (*) after ihead, chead, ohead? Those stars actually appeared as symbols at the top of my document.

Finally it looks like this:

[image]

:)

Comment: I used stars because if you change to a report or book class (`scrreprt` or `scrbook`) the start pages of chapters will be `plain` by default. With the star, you still get the header without any more modifications. The placement of the header is by design, it is huge, and hence should be considered as part of the text body (`includehead` with geometry, `headinclude` with KOMA). Please read about it in chapter 2 of the KOMA documentatin. Even for a worksheet, the margins you set are incredibly insane.